# Java - Stack class can't find memory leak

Tags: java, performance

I've got this question in an interview, and tried to resolve it even after for hours.
The question is: there is a memory leak in this Stack Class, find it and resolve it. Except the fact doubling the capacity when the limit is reached, i can't find the memory leak:

```
public class Stack {

private Object [] elements;
private int size = 0;

public Stack(int initialCapacity) {
    this.elements = new Object[initialCapacity];
}

public void push(Object object) {
    this.ensureCapacity();
    this.elements[size++] = object;
}


public Object pop() {
    if(size == 0)
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    return this.elements[--size];
}

private void ensureCapacity() {

    if(elements.length == size) {

        Object [] old = elements;
        elements = new Object[2 * size + 1];
        System.arraycopy(old, 0, elements, 0, size);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Before: show memory usage
    Stack stack = new Stack(10000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        stack.push("very large String: " + i);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        System.out.println(stack.pop());        
    // After: show memory usage
}

}
```

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. Are you sure it is fair to point out where the 'leak' is,wouldn't that ruin your learning experience? As a hint, at what point in this code should an element no longer be associated with the stack?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there is no homework, except the fact that i want to know the answer. And i've tried so many times before posting the question.

Answer (score 6):

This is an example given in the book `Effective Java`  by Joshua Bloch. The memory leak is in the pop function, when the top element in the stack is removed, the reference is not set to null, hence it can't be garbage collected.